# Cannot open database "test" requested by the login. The login failed

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2008, sql-server-express

I'm failing this for the quadrizillionth time and I understand I will never become a dba.

- I've just restored a database to my local server running SQL Express into "test".
- I've mapped my local db user "testuser" to the database as **db_owner**
- Sql server express is running mixed mode authentication
- I'm trying to connect to the database using the following connection string:

  > "Data Source=(local)\sqlexpress;User Id=testuser;Password=supersecret;Initial Catalog=test;"

Can somebody please tell me what I'm missing here?

Comment: Have you tried those credentials with SQL Management Studio?

Comment: Yes, I can login using those credentials

Comment: And I assume that you can access tables within that database fro SQL MS?

Comment: Yes I can access the database in question...

Comment: When you connect to the database using SQL MS, what is the address of the server you type ( '(local)', '(local/sqlexpress)', '.', '.\sqlexpress')? Can you check you firewall whether it allows port 1433? Can you double check for the typos in connection string?

Comment: I got other websites on my local server to work... So the (local)\SQLEXPRESS or .\SQLEXPRESS really are correct...

Comment: He's connecting to the server fine... it has nothing to do with firewall, or port, or server name, or instance name, or IP address, or SQL browser, or TCP/IP protocol...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible you have an orphaned user. What does this yield?

```
SELECT 
    dp.name, 
    sp.name 
FROM
    sys.database_principals AS dp
FULL OUTER JOIN
    sys.server_principals AS sp
    ON dp.[sid] = sp.[sid]
WHERE 
    dp.name = 'testuser';
```

Basically if your database user "testuser" is not mapped correctly to the login of the same name, the server will have no way to connect you to the right database. You can see the following article for troubleshooting help:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175475%28SQL.100%29.aspx

Comment: I have a login only, I mapped that to the database as db_owner

Comment: Query returns "testuser" "testuser" (columns: name, name)

Comment: In one row or two rows? Did you run the query in database "test"? Also in Management Studio look for the error 18456 under Management > SQL Server Logs > Current. On that line you should see a number next to "State:" - what is that number? Did you assign a default database to the login testuser?

Comment: I'm lost - what does rsbarro say? I don't see any comments from rsbarro.

Comment: sbarro gave a "Auto_Fix" query for orphaned users. The user didn't need a fix. I assigned a default database to the login testuser yes (in the querystring). Error state reads: 38. And your query returned one row..

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that TCP/IP protocol is enabled (in SQL Server Configuration Manager).  Also ensure that SQL Browser service is enabled, started, and automatic (in SSCM as well).  By default these two things for SQL Server Express are not initially configured/started as such.

Comment: Yes a record is returned for your query. User status column reads: 9

Comment: If this were the problem, the error message would be different (unable to connect to the server). Failing on the specified database indicates that connection to the server was successful.

Comment: I just keep on creating users with all rights everytime I restore a database and get it working somehow. But this can't be right... I just want to use my "test" user defined on the server and get it running with that... How can this be such a pain in the ass?

Comment: Because it is better to be secure than wide open by default. Maybe you can describe your process for "creating users with all rights everytime" and how that process differed this time?

Comment: Last time in management studio I created a new login (sql server auth) under 'security'. I gave it server credential "public" and mapped it to the restored database. That gave me access... This time I restored a new database and mapped that same user without avail... By the way, I changed back the connection string to the old database and that didn't work anymore also... :(

Comment: Ok, I just really need access now. What should I do to connect to the database? I created a new login "test2" and set it to "sysadmin" and "public" server roles. I mapped it to the database as "db_owner". Still the same error?!

Comment: Please please help me out here... :S

Comment: I'm not sure what else to offer, because it's hard to tell from your narrative exactly what you're doing. Have you considered using windows authentication?

Comment: I've tried setting Integrated security to SSPI, also the NETWORK SERVICE account has db_owner privileges in the database. But the error is the same... (only it states: Login failed for 'NETWORK SERVICE')